# Find pipe to multiple commands (grep and file)

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Here is my problem : I am trying to parse a lot of files on a system to find some tokens. My tokens are stored in a file, one token on each line (for example token.txt). My path to parse are also stored in an other file, one path on each line (for example path.txt).
I use a combination of `find` and `grep` to do my stuff. Here is one attempt:

```
for path in $(cat path.txt)
do
    for line in $(find $path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -anf token.txt 2>/dev/null);
    do
       #some stuffs here
    done
done
```

It seems to work fine, I don't really know if there is an other way to make it faster though (I am a beginner in programmation and shell).

My problem is : For each file found by the `find` command, I want to get all the files that are compressed. For this, I wanted to use the `file` command. The problem is that I need the output of the `find` command for both `grep` and `file`.

What is the best way to achieve this ? To summarize my problem, I would like something like this :

```
for path in $(cat path.txt)
do
    for line in $(find $path -type f);
    do
        #Use file command to test all the files, and do some stuff
        #Use grep to find some tokens in all the files, and do some stuff
    done 
done
```

I don't know if my explanations are clear, I tried my best.

EDIT : I read that doing `for` loop to read a file is bad, but some people claims that doing `while read` loop is also bad. I am a bit lost to be honest, I can't really find the proper way to do my stuffs.

Comment: How many lines are there in `path.txt` roughly?

Comment: suggestions: use [while and read instead of for loop for reading file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).... use `-exec` option of find... see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/566/find/1845/executing-commands-against-a-found-file#t=201703151350058328169 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/109046

Comment: You don't need `xargs` in the first place: `find "$path" -type f -exec grep -anf token.txt {} \;`.

Comment: I will take a look at your links, thank you. Concerning my path.txt, it varies but I think it will still be around 5, 10 paths.

Comment: A single `find` can look in multiple places... e.g. `find  /etc  /usr/local` will list all the files in both directories, so you can do `find $(cat path.txt) -exec bash -c "...." \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is fine, but here is another way to do it. With this method you won't have to add additional loops to iterate of each item in your configuration files. There are ways to simplify this further, but it would not be as readable.

To test this:
In "${DIR}/path" I have two directories listed (one on each line). Both directories are contained in the same parent directory as this script. In the "${DIR}/token" file, I have three tokens (one on each line) to search for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Directory where this script is located
#
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

#
# Loop through each file contained in our path list
#
for f in $(find $(cat "${DIR}/path") -type f); do
    for c in $(cat "${f}" | grep "$(cat ${DIR}/token)"); do
        echo "${f}"
        echo "${c}"
        # Do your file command here
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will try it.

Comment: No problem. To output only the match found by grep. You can use the -o' flag. i.e: grep -o "$(cat "${DIR}/token");

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
find $(cat places.txt) -type f -exec bash -c 'file "$1" | grep -q compressed && echo $1 looks compressed' _ {} \;
```

**Sample Output**

```
/Users/mark/tmp/a.tgz looks compressed
```

This script is looking in all the places listed in `places.txt` and running a new `bash` shell for each file it finds. Inside the `bash` shell it is testing if the file is compressed and echoing a message if it is - I guess you will do something else but you don't say what.

Another way of writing that more verbosely if you have lots to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r d; do
   find "$d" -type f -exec bash -c '
        file "$1" | grep -q "compressed"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
           echo "$1" is compressed
        else
           echo "$1" is not compressed
        fi' _ {} \;
done < <(cat places.txt)
```